# Customizing / Editing Dynamic Text for <path> in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, dynamic-text, file-path

To encourage GIS users here to adhere more rigidly to the existing folder architecture as well as demonstrate the functionality of dynamic text, I'm trying to update one of our templates so that I can automatically generate Layout title using dynamic text to display the file path, but only with select levels of the folder tree.

example, for a project path:

```
D:\PROJECT_FOLDERS\PROJECT_AREA\CLIENT\PROJECT\PROJECT_NO\SUB_SECTION\GIS\PROJECTS\Project1.mxd
```

I'm trying to generate as dynamic text (separated by spaces):

```
CLIENT  PROJECT  PROJECT_NO  SUB_SECTION
```

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that Dynamic Text offers the string manipulation that you seek here.  Instead I think you will need to use what I call "pseudo-dynamic text".

Some time ago I released an eLearning video on [Using Pseudo-dynamic Text in ArcPy Map Automation](http://discoverspatial.com/courses/using-pseudo-dynamic-text-in-arcpy-map-automation). It is not free but if you do want to pursue that as option, and need a quick intro to the coding pattern involved, then it is only a few dollars to purchase.

The coding pattern is to use Python to set a variable to the path string manipulated to be the path with spaces between its parts, and then to have a recognizable string in your static text element called perhaps `StringVal`, that ArcPy searches for and replaces with the contents of your variable.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author and presenter of the eLearning video tutorial mentioned above